# Informix divide by zero error

Tags: sql, informix

I have a query which is erroring out with a divide by zero error. I have isolated the part of the query which errors and tried to fix it using an NVL but it's just not going well, can someone spot my error?

```
select  warehouse.ware_code,
    warehouse.desc_text,
    maingrp.maingrp_code,
    maingrp.desc_text,
    prodgrp.prodgrp_code,
    prodgrp.desc_text,
    left(product.part_code,7) Parent_Product_code,
    product.part_code,
    product.desc_text,
    sum(salesstat.order_qty - salesstat.return_qty) Total_Sales,
    sum((salesstat.order_qty - salesstat.return_qty) / 6) Average_Weekly_Sales,
    sum(((salesstat.order_qty - salesstat.return_qty) / 6) * 4) Average_Monthly_Sales,
    '??' Note,
    sum(prodstatus.onhand_qty) Stock_On_Hand,
    sum(orderstat.order_qty - orderstat.cancel_qty) Outstanding_orders,
    sum(prodstatus.onhand_qty - (orderstat.order_qty - orderstat.cancel_qty)) Stock_Available,
    --CASE
    --WHEN nvl(sum(salesstat.order_qty - salesstat.return_qty),0) = 0
    --  THEN 999
    --ELSE  sum(prodstatus.onhand_qty / ((salesstat.order_qty - salesstat.return_qty) / 6))
    --END as Weeks_Stock_Remaining,
    '??' Stock_ordered,
    '??' Production_date
from
    warehouse,
    warereptdetl,
    maingrp,
    prodgrp,
    product,
    prodstatus,
    salesstat,
    orderstat,
    Statint
where   warehouse.cmpy_code = maingrp.cmpy_code
and warehouse.cmpy_code = warereptdetl.cmpy_code
and warehouse.cmpy_code = prodgrp.cmpy_code
and warehouse.cmpy_code = product.cmpy_code
and warehouse.cmpy_code = salesstat.cmpy_code
and warehouse.cmpy_code = prodstatus.cmpy_code
and warehouse.cmpy_code = orderstat.cmpy_code
and warehouse.cmpy_code = statint.cmpy_code
and product.ware_code = prodstatus.ware_code
and product.ware_code = warehouse.ware_code
and product.ware_code = salesstat.ware_code
and product.ware_code = orderstat.ware_code
and product.ware_code = warereptdetl.ware_code
and product.part_code = salesstat.part_code
and product.part_code = orderstat.part_code
and product.part_code = prodstatus.part_code
and product.prodgrp_code = salesstat.prodgrp_code
and product.prodgrp_code = orderstat.prodgrp_code
and product.prodgrp_code = prodgrp.prodgrp_code
and product.maingrp_code = salesstat.maingrp_code
and product.maingrp_code = orderstat.maingrp_code
and product.maingrp_code = maingrp.maingrp_code
and salesstat.year_num = statint.year_num
and salesstat.int_num = statint.int_num
and salesstat.stat_type_code = statint.type_code
and orderstat.year_num = statint.year_num
and orderstat.int_num = statint.int_num
and orderstat.stat_type_code = statint.type_code
and warehouse.cmpy_code = 'AB'
and warereptdetl.warereptgrp_code = 'NSW'
and product.ware_code = 'HP1'
and product.status_ind <> 3
and left(product.part_code,2) = '21'
and statint.year_num = 2016
and statint.int_num between 29 AND 34
--and   statint.int_num = 29
and statint.type_code = 'WLY'
Group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

The commented out part is where I have tried to put in a fix, if I comment it out the query runs fine (albeit a bit slow).

The second part of the question is something that you may not be able to answer without having access to my database but if I run the query for 1, 2 or even 3 weeks (statint.int_num) the query comes back in under 1 minute. as soon as I push it out to 6 weeks (which is what I need) the query takes just over 40 minutes to return the results.

I can't see anywhere in the query where I have created a cartesian but I have stared at it for so long I may be missing it.

Comment: just for chagrins put 6.0 instead of 6. or force the result to be cast as a decimal.   Integer math may be occurring which is rounding your values to 0 instead of expected decimals. `CASE
    wHEN nvl(sum(salesstat.order_qty - salesstat.return_qty),0) = 0
      THEN 999
    ELSE  sum(prodstatus.onhand_qty / ((salesstat.order_qty - salesstat.return_qty) / 6.0))
    END as Weeks_Stock_Remaining,`  OR... if order_Qty = 5 and return_qty = 5 then 5-5 = 0... 0/6 =0 and you now divide by zero error.. but I think your case handled that...  though... I don't think you want the sum...

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBJG3_2.5.0/com.ibm.gen_busug.doc/c_fgl_odiagora_030.htm?lang=en  states: When dividing INTEGERs or SMALLINTs, Informix rounds the result ( 7 / 2 = 3 ), while ORACLE doesn't, because it does not have a native integer data type ( 7 / 2 = 3.5 ).  So if it's rounding it may round to 0...

Comment: using 6.0 gave the same divide by zero error unfortunately. Thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case statement:

```
sum(salesstat.order_qty - salesstat.return_qty)
```

may be non zero, but the individual

```
salesstat.order_qty - salesstat.return_qty
```

which is what you're dividing by, may contain zeroes.

EDIT

To clarify,

```
sum(prodstatus.onhand_qty / ((salesstat.order_qty - salesstat.return_qty) / 6))
```

may have zeroes in the denomiator because it is a sum of several fractions. Just because all of the denominators sum up to a non-zero number doesn't mean that all the denominators are non-zero.

Comment: Thanks, changed it to: `CASE WHEN nvl(sum(salesstat.order_qty - salesstat.return_qty),0) = 0 THEN 999 ELSE sum(prodstatus.onhand_qty) / (sum(salesstat.order_qty - salesstat.return_qty) / 6.0) END as Weeks_Stock_Remaining` and it seems to work :)

Comment: No worries =). I know how it feels to stare at code that just refuses to work. For your second question, I had a think and the only thing I could come up with was that the blowup may be in all those joins. Your case statement looks like you're using postgresql  in which case you're doing cross joins on all those tables which would definitely get very big VERY quickly. Instead of specifying your conditions in the WHERE clause, you should do it in the FROM clause e.g. FROM warehouse w inner join maingrp mg on w.cmpy_code = mg.cmpy_code.

Comment: I don't know what it is using, it's the back end of our main system here, there are no schemas or anything (I have literally had to write a VBA app to pull table and column listings then poll through and shade common named columns for me as a starting point for writing these behemoth queries) There is no documentation and the third party company that wrote the system is very protective of their structure. Makes me really appreciate the in house designed and maintained Oracle and MSSQL DB's we had at my last workplace :).

Comment: I should look into how to do the joins as you have suggested, I have avoided it because I always did the *= in my old Oracle / MSSQL days and in the from clause seems so much more difficult but I think I have to take a leap of faith and learn how to do it properly :p

Comment: Wow, and I thought I had it bad. At least I have a schema =P. Let me know if changing the joins work. Try removing all the commas and joining them with "left join" or "inner join" and specifying conditions in the FROM clause. Frankly I'm amazed it ran even for a three week time period. All the functions in your query look like postgresql ones so I recommend starting from the documentation there.

Comment: Just an FYI, Because our database is a douchebag, I ended up writing 3 queries, it's a VBA app anyway so it's all good, just splice the data together in Excel programmatically. the run time is now down to 29 seconds for 6 runs with different variables, when I did it with one query it was 40 mins just for 1 run. Thanks for all your help on it though, I took plenty of learnings from it :)

Comment: No worries at all, mate. I'm glad it worked out for you in the end. Maybe I'll have a VBA question one day that I'll need your help for =).